# What configuration should I do on the targetting domain from a CNAME domain?

Tags: server, cpanel, cname

domain A is on server A, while domain B is on a different server B.

The domain A, has a CNAME that points to the domain B. However, when I visit domain A, I get a message from cPanel stating

> "SORRY! If you are the owner of this website, please contact your
>   hosting provider: webmaster@domain.com It is possible you have reached
>   this page because:...."

My question is what configuration/setting should I do in server B, where my main domain is hosted?

I use a cpanel on VPS hosting.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A CNAME is an alias and not generally used for domain names except to equate one domain name to another. This is clearly not what you want. You want both domain names to go to their perspective sites. This requires an IP address for both site servers. If you do not know the IP addresses for both servers, you will have to contact your web host company for this information. You will want an A record in your DNS pointing each domain name to the IP address for the server that the site resides on.

The error you are getting is likely the system telling you that it does not have the site for that domain name. This is expected since the site for domain A is not on server B. This confusion comes about using the alias CNAME instead of using an A record for both domains.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a CNAME record is not required **at all**.

As you are attempting to show Domain B via Domain A, I would simply set an @ A record Domain A to the IP address of Domain B and set it up in cPanel as an **Alias**. This way, both domains will mirror the content from each other, using only one file system. It's then also advisable to set up a www CNAME that points to Domain A.

You can obtain the IP address for Domain B to use in your A records for Domain A by running this in Command Prompt:

```
>ping domainb.com
```

cPanel shows that message because it does not have an Alias entry in httpd.conf for Domain A, thus it does not know which website to display. If you add Domain A to Aliases in cPanel now, you'll find it will most likely work.